# Reinstalling Owncloud 9 on Ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, owncloud

I wanted to create a fresh install of the program owncloud again

```
$ sudo apt-get remove owncloud
$ sudo apt-get purge owncloud
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo rm -rf /var/wwww/owncloud
```

After this, I wanted to install owncloud again

```
$ sudo apt-get install owncloud
```

The second installation of owncloud did not create /var/www/owncloud again, as the first did. So, what did I do wrong and is there a possibility to install it normally again?

Comment: Don't you need `rm -r` to get rid of `/var/www/owncloud`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typing mistake. The problem is not to get rid of /var/www/owncloud, but to get it back with a new installation of owncloud

Comment: Ok, I see. Is your only problem that that directory does not exist? What if you create it manually and then run the `apt-get install` again? Any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to purge all dependencies then by using reinstall flag you should accomplish it as the following lines:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge owncloud-*
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall owncloud
```

Answer (score 2):

So, I found the mistake that I made. I did not remove ownlcoud completely.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge owncloud
$ sudo apt-get purge owncloud-*
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt-get install owncloud
```

After the procedure above, owncloud was freshly reinstalled

Comment: Or just without apt-get like written here http://www.kwoxer.de/2016/05/24/owncloud-update-durchf%C3%BChren-die-updater-routine/ :)